# Can blasters run out of ammo or jam?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, blasters

In season 2, episode 7 of The Mandalorian, Din is fighting some pirates and his blaster appears to either run out of ammo or jam up such that he can no longer use the blaster.

Out-of-universe, I realize the explanation for this is the [Rule of Funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny) as well as forcing our hero to physically engage with the Bad Guys. But I was wondering if there was an in-universe precedent for blasters suddenly failing to work (whether it be running out of ammo or jamming up).

Comment: Season 2,  episode 8 may furnish some further evidence.

Comment: Ah - I’ve not gotten there yet.

Comment: But even so, is this new to The Mandalorian? Or have other Star Wars stories had this happen also?

Comment: "*Thousands of years before the Galactic Civil War, these projectile weapons gave way to **energy blasters that are easier to reload** and more effective than the ancient weapons. No matter their specialized purpose, the basic function is largely the same. Using an energy source, often a cartridge filled with energized gas, a blaster propels a glowing particle beam at high speed. Depending on the gas and design of the blaster, different color bolts are possible. Red is the most common, but green, blue, and yellow are potential variants."* ***The Star Wars Book***

Comment: @Valorum So it's something that only comes into play when it is useful to the story, like running out of fuel in The Last Jedi...

Comment: @SethMMorton - Precisely. In the novelisation for Rogue One, we learn that Baize's rapid-fire gun can fire 40,000 bolts before needing to be reloaded. Assuming it's as fast as **ten uzis sellotaped together**, that's still two entire minutes of continuous fire.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yeah. Go ahead and close this one.

Comment: The clone trooper rifle (DC-15A blaster carbine) *canonically* has a 500 shot capacity. The smaller pistol they carry as a sidearm has a 50 shot capacity. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ztyp.png

Answer (score -1):

In Star Wars blasters can technically run out of ammo.

Except that it isn't "ammo" its gas/power that is required to create the blaster "bolts" that fire from the blaster.

In this way, a blaster has a limited amount of "shots" that can be used up

Comment: This appears to be an assertion without any evidence to back it up.

Comment: IIRC, a number of the (at least Legends canon) various encyclopedias or visual guides make mention of this.  You might try to find a page.

Comment: What's the difference between 'ammo' and a substance that used up making the shots?